# How do I use a function result to call a variable name?

Tags: javascript

I have a `<select>` with available jobs divided by city, seen here:

```
<select id="jobs">
    <option value="columbus">Columbus, OH: Material Handler</option>
    <option value="columbus">Columbus, OH: Fulfillment Center Worker</option>
    <option value="baltimore">Baltimore, MD: Material Handler</option>
  </select>
```

and I am pulling the value as such:

```
var jobName = document.getElementById("jobs").value;
```

which returns the result just fine. For the first option I get:

```
columbus
```

which is great, now my question is, how do I use this to call another variable, for instance:

```
var columbus = ['Columbus','3500 Southwest Blvd',', 8 am to 3:30 pm'],
    baltimore = ['Baltimore','913 Old Philadelphia Rd',', 8 am to 3 pm'],
    currentCity = columbus[0] 
console.log(currentCity);
```

console would return:

```
Columbus
```

but, how do I use the `jobName` to update the currentCity dynamically like:

```
currentCity = jobName[0]
```

Comment: Just `currentCity = jobName` ? `jobName` is not an array, it's a string.

Comment: Ok this works great, thank you, but How do I call the second string in the array with this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than having different variables, you should use an object to hold all the city information, like this:

```
var cities = {
  colombus: ['Columbus','3500 Southwest Blvd',', 8 am to 3:30 pm'],
  baltimore: ['Baltimore','913 Old Philadelphia Rd',', 8 am to 3 pm']
};
```

Then you could write

```
var currentCity = cities[jobName][0];
```

Comment: I was about to answer that.

Comment: Awesome I think I like this better, I will try this out thanks!

Comment: I cant get this to work?
`$("#jobs-form").submit(function(e) {       
      e.preventDefault();
    var jobName = document.getElementById("jobs").value;
    var cities = {
        columbus: ['Columbus','3500 Southwest Blvd',', 8 am to 3:30 pm'],
        baltimore: ['Baltimore','913 Old Philadelphia Rd',', 8 am to 3 pm']
    };
    var currentCity = cities[jobName][0];
    var currentAddress = cities[jobName][1];
    var currentTime = cities[jobName][2];
    $('.job').slideDown();
    $('.job .name').text(currentCity);
});`

my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/chrisburk/r5Q5L/12/

Comment: @ChrisBurk Your option values in the jsfiddle start with an uppercase letter, not lowercase like in the question. The keys in the object need to match.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to "look up" a value based on a key. Often, this is done using what's known as a "dictionary" - or, more formally, an "[associate array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)" (sometimes also referred to as a "[hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)" - although a hash table is just a one type of dictionary).

JavaScript has something similar that you can use called *objects*. They are written using curly braces `{}`, and the keys are separated from values by a colon `:`. Keys  are strings, but the quotes are usually optional. Values can be anything you want.

```
var cities = {
    columbus: ['Columbus','3500 Southwest Blvd',', 8 am to 3:30 pm'],
    baltimore: ['Baltimore','913 Old Philadelphia Rd',', 8 am to 3 pm']
};
```

Once you have your key (`jobName` in your example), you can simply use the `cities` object to look up whatever you need.

```
var jobInfo = cities[jobName],
    currentCity = jobInfo[0];

console.log(currentCity);
```

---

Side note: JavaScript objects aren't really fully-fledged dictionaries. In most other language, dictionaries can actually use many different types of values for the key (for example, integers), but in JavaScript the key can generally only be a string.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I tried this with no luck, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? Here is my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/chrisburk/2dUu2/2/

Comment: @ChrisBurk: The option values in your HTML start with a capital letter, the names in your table with a lower case letter. Note that HTML you posted in the question here also starts with lower case letters.

Comment: Thank you, that was the issue!